# What neurotransmitters can be suppressed/promoted by tDCS

Tags: neuroscience, tdcs

Transcranial Direct Current Stimulation (tDCS) has been shown to [modify suppression in the visual cortex](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0036220) and [GABA suppression in motor control](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811914004558).

As of now, the exact neurobiological mechanism that creates this phenomenon isn't known, but what are the neurotransmitters that can be modified by this methodology? To what degree can these neurotransmitter levels be manipulated? Are there limitations to the parts of the brain this technique can be applied?